How to calculate the functional derivative of this composite function?
I think I am not unfamiliar with the functional derivative, while recently I encounter a paper which gives the functional derivative expression like this
$$W=\ln[\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{N!h^{3N}}e^{-\beta PV}\int e^{\int[\beta\mu-\beta U(\textbf{r})]\rho_M(\textbf{r})d\textbf{r}}e^{-\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{p_i^2}{2m}}d\textbf{p}_id\textbf{r}_i]$$
in which
$$\rho_M(\textbf{r})=\sum_{i=1}^N \delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_i)$$
$$u(\textbf(r)) = \beta\mu-\beta U(\textbf{r})$$
This is a standard grand partion function in the statistical mechanics. The paper states that
$$\frac{\delta W}{\delta u(\textbf{r})} = <\rho_M(\textbf{r})>$$, which denotes the ensemble average of the density $\rho_M(\textbf{r})$. And
$$<\rho_M(\textbf{r})>=\frac{\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{N!h^{3N}}e^{-\beta PV}\int \rho_M(\textbf{r})e^{\int[\beta\mu-\beta U(\textbf{r})]\rho_M(\textbf{r})d\textbf{r}}e^{-\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{p_i^2}{2m}}d\textbf{p}_id\textbf{r}_i}{e^W}$$
I am wondering why the functional derivative of $W$ is equal to $<\rho_M(\textbf{r})>$? Thanks

There are TeX typos probably. The differential $d\mathbf r $ in the exponent does not make sense.

@RolandF Hi, thanks, yeah I have corrected the typo error. There is a "\int" operator before the exponent with respect to the coordinate vector 'r'

Use chain rules and commutativity
$$\delta \int = \int \delta$$
$$\frac{\delta }{\delta u} \log f(g(u))= \frac{f'(g(u))}{f(g(u))} \ \frac{\delta}{\delta u} g(u)$$
with
$$ \frac{\delta}{\delta u} \ g(u) = \int \frac{\delta}{\delta u} e^{\int\  u \ \rho \ dx}\  dy=\int  \ e^{\int u \rho \ dx} \ \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta u} \int u \rho \ dx \right) dy = \int  \ e^{\int u \rho \ dx} \  \int \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta u}\left(u \rho \right) \ dx \right) dy$$

Hi, thanks for the update. I understand the chain rule is the key point here, while I am in fact quite confused about this variational form. According to wiki link, $F[\rho]=\int (x, \rho(x))dx$ is the standard functional form, right? While here the integral with respect to 'u' is located on exponent, and it is enclosed by another multivariable integral. Is it a violation of the definition? thanks

Forget integrals, they are bilinear maps from domains and function to the number field.
$$\int_{a(u)}^{b(u)} \  f_u(x)  dx \ = \langle (a(u), b(u)) \ , \ f_u\rangle$$  with the effect that the differential is
$$\delta_u \langle (a(u), b(u)) \ , \ f_u\rangle = \delta u \left( - \langle (a'(u), b(u)) \ , \ f_u\rangle+ \langle (a(u), b'(u)) \ , \ f_u\rangle  +  \langle (a(u), b(u)) \ , \ \partial_u f_u\rangle  \right) $$

I think I understand your idea here, so for the expression bove,

we are only focusing on the deviation of the number field relation with the functional variation, right? $$\delta F = \int \frac{\delta F}{\delta u}\delta u$$, $F$ is the number field here. The functional form is not so important
